# Cannot install plugins on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and am trying to get a simple pipeline setup and struggling with the plugins page. I want to install the Azure credentials plugin but in the Plugin Manager page, when I select the plugin checkbox, there is no "Install" button so I don't know what to do next.

Tried on latest Chrome and Firefox with same issue. No errors in the console.

I looked at the documentation and it does not describe any reasons why the buttons won't appear. I am unsure if this is a bug or a problem with the documentation.

I am running v2.249.1 LTS version on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the Plugin Manager page?

Comment: I have the same issue. Tried both the latest LTS and latest 2.260 on windows 2016 and 2019. Install buttons are missing.

Comment: I am also seeing the same issues on Ubuntu 20.04. I have tried both Jenkins 2.235.1 as well as the weekly release 2.260 and neither of them are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same bug here, try Jenkins 2.249.1 fresh installation using ubuntu 20.04 and cannot install plugin from web UI https://prnt.sc/uudmrw

So I downgrade jenkins to older version to version 2.235.1, now I can install plugin from web ui https://prnt.sc/uue9tl

sudo apt-get install jenkins=2.235.1

Answer (score 1):

Because this issue seems to be present in both 2.235.1 as ell as 2.260, the weekly release, I would recommend using the Jenkins CLI in the meantime. You can find the documentation here: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/managing/cli/ - I just used it and it works well. Do not forget to download the `jenkins-cli.jar` file as well as generted an API token.

```
wget https://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
```

Comment: Just wanted to add that ordinarily we can use HTTP to access the localhost instead, so the using the command `wget http://localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar` after restarting the Jenkins server works for me.